# Showing a dialog on top right corner

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to create a dialog with a custom layout and no title. Also, the dialog should open on the top right corner of the screen. Here is the screenshot of what I want.

[image]

Comment: Great! You only have to start that project now. Please write some code and get back to us.

Comment: I tried but the RequestFeature.noTitle is also not working in xamarin. Moreover I dont have any idea on how to position it correctly. Thats why I did not post any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used below code to achieve my requirement.

```
Window window = dialog.Window;
WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.Attributes;
wlp.Gravity = GravityFlags.Top | GravityFlags.Right;
window.Attributes = wlp;
```

Answer (score 0):

In xamarin.iOS is something like PopOverViewContainer. May it's in Android the same.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe by changing the gravity of the dialog using the WindowManager Attributes property:

```
Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity);
AlertDialog alertName = builder.Create();
alertName.SetTitle("Warning...");
alertName.SetIcon(Android.Resource.Drawable.IcDialogAlert);
alertName.SetMessage("This is a warning message");
alertName.SetButton("OK", (s, ev) =>
{
    return;
});
alertName.Show();
var window = alertName.Window;
var wlp = window.Attributes;
wlp.Gravity = GravityFlags.Top;
wlp.Flags = WindowManagerFlags.DimBehind;
window.Attributes = wlp;
```

You should be able to change the gravity parameter and the flags (which currently stops the background to the dialog from dimming